# Accessing Array Data in Object

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to access a piece of data in an array of arrays that (I believe) is in an object (this may not be the right term though).

When I do `print_r` on this: `$order_total_modules->process()` I get...

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
            [code] => ot_subtotal 
            [title] => Sub-Total: 
            [text] => $49.99 
            [value] => 49.99 
            [sort_order] => 1 
            ) 
[1] => Array (
            [code] => ot_total 
            [title] => Total: 
            [text] => $0.00 
            [value] => 0 
            [sort_order] => 12 
            ) 
)
```

If I run `echo $order_total_modules->process()[1][3];`, I should get "0", because that is the 3rd element of the 2nd array... right?  Yet, I get an error.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It's the third but not `3`, it is `value`.

Comment: Array dereferencing is only available as of >=PHP5.4

Comment: That's an associative array, not a numeric-indexed one.  `[1]['value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is the third element counting from 0, the index is not `3` it is an associative array with the index `value`:

Available in PHP >=5.4.0:

```
echo $order_total_modules->process()[1]['value'];
```

Or PHP < 5.4.0:

```
$result = $order_total_modules->process();
echo $result[1]['value'];
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit - it's 5.4+, not 5.5 for array dereferencing.

Comment: Michael beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an associative array via an integer index(unless the index is an actial integer).
So in this case use :
`[1]['code']` to access what woulde be [1][0] with a 'normal' array.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a var first:

```
$ar = $order_total_modules->process();
echo $ar[1]['value'];
```

The second level array is an assoc, which means that the key is not numeric, which means that you need to call the name of the key, hence the 'value'.